# Length of pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I searched and I didn't find anything that is like my situation. I have a `float**` and well I know that it is a special type of pointer because it is an array of elements that have a `float*` that points to another zone of memory. So I write a simple code to detect the length of this matrix, to be more precise the length of the float + elements inside `float**`; But it results in a segmentation fault.
Here there is my code:

```
int Loader:: Length(float** length)
{
    int count=0;
    while(*length[count]!='\0'){
        count++;

    }
    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
    return count;

}
```

Sorry for my english and sorry for the stupid question. Thanks to all.

Comment: Note: A `**` is not a "double pointer", but a "pointer to a pointer". A "double pointer" would commonly be understood as `double *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a `float**` and well I know that it is a special type of pointer

Not really. A double pointer is just a special case of a single pointer. It is still a pointer to `T`, and that `T` happens to be `float*`.

> because it is an array of elements

No! It *is* not an array. It **may point to the first element** of an array.

> that have a float* that points to another zone of memory.

So, more precisely, a `float**` may point to the first element of an array full of `float*`. Where those individual `float*`s point to is another story.

> So I write a simple code to detect the length of this matrix,

You cannot. When all you have is a pointer to the beginning of an array, then the **size information is already lost**.

That is, unless you have a **convention** for the last element, like C-style strings or string literals with their `'\0'` terminator. Which brings us to the next point...

> ```
> int Loader:: Length(float** length)
> {
>     int count=0;
>     while(*length[count]!='\0'){
> ```

Here's the culprit. Not all arrays are terminated by `'\0'`. In fact, it's not typical at all for arbitrary arrays containing a zero separator.

So unless the array to whose first element `length` points to actually contains an element which compares to `'\0'`, then your loop will go one element past the end of the array and try to read from there. In that very moment, **undefined behaviour** is invoked and your program can do anything, including random crashes.

---

The best solution to your problem is to use `std::vector`, because a `std::vector` always knows its own size. So make it `std::vector<float*>`. Or better yet, a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

In fact, if it's really a matrix, then make it `std::vector<float>`, store all contents contiguously, additionally store the matrix' width somewhere, and always calculate the offset for X/Y.

Comment: Thanks finally I understand.  Thanks endeed ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by your expectation that all arrays operate in the same way as literal character strings, ie that they are automatically terminated by a 0 value. Neither C++ or C work that way.

If you want the array length you need to do one of the following:

1. Pass the length along with the array everywhere.
2. Use a std::vector, std::deque or std::array instead of an array, and get the length from that.

Comment: ok but i'm curious.. why it return segmentation fault when i trid to access to elements?? (*length[count])

Comment: @P.Carlino Because at some point you will try to access a memory address that you haven't reserved and the OS will complain.

Comment: but it is reserved...trying with length[num1][num2] it works

Comment: But if your array of float pointers doesn't have a null pointer at the end (ie you haven't set it) then what's going to stop your code running past the end into memory you haven't reserved?